# UIApplication.shared.open(_ url: URL,etc.) doesn't open anything

Tags: swift, uiapplication, openurl

I have added "instagram" to my LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the Info.plist file but it still doesn't open up neither safari nor instagram when the following function is called:

```
func openinstagram () {
    let instaurl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.instagram.com/(myusername)/?hl=de")
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instaurl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(instaurl, options: [:] ) { (sucess) in
            print("url opened")
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't tell me anything but "url opened" in the Log

What is the solution to this? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out this.

`URL(fileURLWithPath:)` use to get file starting with /

`URL(string:)` is create web url

```
func openinstagram () {
    if let instaurl = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/(myusername)/?hl=de"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instaurl) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(instaurl)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(instaurl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is missing an `if` keyword on the `canOpenURL` line and a corresponding closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong API

- `URL(fileURLWithPath` is for file system URLs starting with `/`
- `URL(string` is for URLs starting with a scheme (`https://`, `file://`)

And the string interpolation of `myusername` looks wrong (missing backslash and extraneous slash before the query question mark).

```
    if let instaurl = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/\(myusername)?hl=de"),
       UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instaurl) { ...
```

Answer (score -1):

**XCode 15 & iOS 17.2**

***Below Sample code for Uber App.***

Add below scheme in your PList file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>uber</string>
</array>
```

Use below code to open the app:

```
let appURLScheme = "uber://"
    
guard let appURL = URL(string: appURLScheme) else {
    return
}
    
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(appURL)
}
```